# Pandas "usecols" doesn't seems work perfectly

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading below excel with below python code but not getting any idea why the first column header has ".1" even though set to ignore the first column. Any idea please? many thanks in advance.

[image]

python script

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.system('cls')
df = pd.read_excel('test_1\Book1.xlsx','sheet1', header=0,  skiprows=1, usecols='B:D',index_col= 0, nrows=5)
print(df)
```

I am very confused about ".1" in the first column name header "PIA IM Equity.1" in the below result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the file you have two columns named "PIA IM Equity" when reading pandas will rename the second identical column by adding .1 in the name. If you would have a third column with the same name it would have added .2 in it.

Comment: thank you, that seems to be happening but my question is why panda is reading  the first column even though the code set to ignore the first column?

Comment: when the file is opened it first needs to see what is there to understand what to include. 
so the procedure(I suspect ) is 1.Pandas opensthe file. 2.It sees what names there are 3.finds out if there is a duplicate, 4.it renames duplicates , and finally filters out the columns specified in "usecols".